# Creating relationship in Core Data to perform deletion

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data

I am new to core data just started learning the new ideas in core data.

I have core data database which has three entity **Student**,**Department** and an entity for Mapping Student and department.Let name it as **StudentDepartment**

Student will have all student details with a primary key studentID
Department will have  department details with a primary key departmentID

StudentDepartment will have studentID and DepartmentID as foreign key.

Multiple student can be enrolled in a department and a same student can be enrolled to multiple department.

How to create this schema in core data.
If am deleting a studentID in student table subsequent row should be deleted in  StudentDepartment table. Similarly if am deleting departmentID in department table subsequent rows should be deleted in StudentDepartment.How to make this relationship by using core data.

Please provide me a xcmodel.

Comment: Watch this series https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G36_91H4CKE

Answer (score 0):

CoreData isn't a database, it's an object store that happens to (sometimes) be implemented on top of a relational database.

The practical result of that is that you really don't need to explicitly create a separate table for relationship mapping.  Instead you create your two entities and then create a relationship between the two.  From your description, it sounds like you want a many-to-many relationship between the two.  At an implementation level, core data will magically create the needed relationship table.

Additionally, you can establish a delete-rule for each side of the relationship that mandates what to do when an item is deleted.  Pin this case, you'll want to set the delete rule for both to nullify, which will break the relationship when either end is deleted.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please create and show me a structure ? So no need of third table and primary keys core data will create it for me ?

Comment: Not just relation ship mapping.i also need to add rows in the third table .Will it be possible to access relationship table that was internally created by core data.I need to insert object to this mapping table.